# Determine if one div is a sibling directly below and adjacent to another div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs and a reference to two that are siblings adjacent to each other. The first div, which I'll call div2 is above div3. How can I tell using jQuery that div2 is directly above div3. Example:

```
<div id="root">
   <div id="div1" />
   <div id="div2" />
   <div id="div3" />
   <div id="div4" />
</div>
```

Comment: *Visually* or *structurally*?

Comment: Both visually and structurally.

Comment: Please note that your HTML is (presumably unintentionally!) misleading. What you have there is a series of `div`s where each is nested within the previous one. `<div/>` is `<div>` in HTML. (It would be `<div></div>` in JSX or XHTML.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, "how do I tell whether `div2` is immediately before `div3`," the answer is that you can check `previousElementSibling` or jQuery's `prev`:

```
// If `div3` and `div2` are DOM elements
if (div3.previousElementSibling === div2) {
    // ...
```

```js
const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
const div3 = document.getElementById("div3");

console.log(div3.previousElementSibling === div2);
```

```html
<div id="root">
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
   <div id="div3"></div>
   <div id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

```
// If `div3` and `div2` are jQuery objects
if (div3.prev()[0] === div2[0]) {
    // ...
```

```js
const div2 = $("#div2");
const div3 = $("#div3");

console.log(div3.prev()[0] === div2[0]);
```

```html
<div id="root">
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
   <div id="div3"></div>
   <div id="div4"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to see if they're *visually* one above the other, you'll want to look at their [bounding rectangles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).